# Regex: Non-Word Not Recognised at the Beginning of an Expression

Tags: regex, expression

I'm using a standard regex expression as a password check, which as far as I can see should accept non-word characters (\W) at the beginning of the expression, but doesn't. The regex is designed to require a minimum of 8 characters, and a combination of at least 1 lower, 1 upper, 1 number and 1 nonword character.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
\b(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W])\b.*
```

E.g.

```
T3st1ng!
```

is identified

```
!T3sting
```

is not.

Comment: I think you need `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,}$`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew and kzrw. It was one of those questions I worked out almost as soon as I had posted this, but both your suggestions are neater and cleaner.

Comment: Are you working in Java? Please consider accepting the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM3gN8/1)

Instead of `\b` you need `^` and `$` anchors. Moreover, you do not have to set the lookahead length check, it can be moved to the `.` part at the end. Also, no need using single shorthand class inside a character class, replace `[\d]` with `\d` for a cleaner expression.

Answer (score 0):

Word boundary `\b` is a virtual space between a non-word characters and word characters.
Word characters are all alphanumeric ones. `!` is a non-word character, so your !T3sting won't work.

And you don't need that if you are checking for password only.

Correct one is:

```
(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).*
```